# Image Carousel Video Autoplay true or False

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, reactjs, carousel

I want to set `autoplay` true if it is video and false if it is image. I tried using `setState` inside `autoplay` as given below but it is throwing an error:

> autoPlay={this.setState({ autoplayvideo: true })} Type 'void' is not
>   assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

```
<Carousel dynamicHeight={true} showThumbs={false}   >
  {this.state.items.map((imageList, key) => {
    if (imageList.SourceType == "Video")
      return (<div>

        <video width="320" height="240" controls autoPlay={this.setState({ autoplayvideo: true })} >
          <source src={imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : ''} type="video/mp4" ></source>
        </video>

        <p className={styles.legends} onClick={() => { this._onClickItem(imageList.Title) }}>{imageList.Title}</p>
      </div>)
    if (imageList.SourceType == "Text")
      return (<div>

        <img src={imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : ''} />

        <p className={styles.legends} onClick={() => { this._onClickItem(imageList.Title) }}>{imageList.Title}</p>
      </div>)
  })}
</Carousel>
```

Comment: you want to set the autoplay of video, right? and not the autoplay of your carousel?

Comment: yes autoplay for video but ony when i am on video when carousel move to image it should stop ,current its keep on playing even if i am move to another image

Comment: This error is because you are using `setState` method in your `autoplay` attribute, which returns `void` after setting the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is throwing an error because you are using `setState` method in your `autoPlay` attribute, which returns `void` after setting the state.

Try using something like below:

```
<Carousel dynamicHeight={true} showThumbs={false}   >
  {this.state.items.map((imageList, key) => {
    if (imageList.SourceType == "Video") {
      this.setState({ autoplayvideo: true });
      return (
        <div>
          <video width="320" height="240" controls autoPlay={this.state.autoplayvideo} >
            <source src={imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : ''} type="video/mp4" ></source>
          </video>
          <p className={styles.legends} onClick={() => { this._onClickItem(imageList.Title) }}>{imageList.Title}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (imageList.SourceType == "Text") {
      this.setState({ autoplayvideo: false });
      return (
        <div>
          <img src={imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : ''} />
          <p className={styles.legends} onClick={() => { this._onClickItem(imageList.Title) }}>{imageList.Title}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })}
</Carousel>
```

**Update**:

If this is giving below error:

> Invariant Violation: Minified React error #185;

Then this is because we are setting the state multiple times inside render method.

So, in this case I think you may take leverage of `onChange` method of Carousel to write a function which will check if the next slide is video or image and then you can set the state property to `true/false`.

Check below GitHub reference for implementation of `onChange` method.

[react-responsive-carousel: main.js](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/src/main.js).

Comment: Let me know if this works or I will suggest you another solution.

Comment: if i add this my webpart goes Invariant Violation: Minified React error #185;

Comment: no syntax error but webpart is blank with console giving this error Invariant Violation: Minified React error #185;

Comment: Oh I forgot...this is because we are setting the state multiple times inside render method....In this case I think you may take leverage of `onChange` method of Carousel to write a function which will check if the next slide is video or image and then you can set the state property to true/false.

Comment: ok any example do you have

Comment: I am afraid but complete example according to your requirement is not there. But you can check how you can write the `onChange` function on carousel, [here](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/src/main.js).

Comment: Let me give a try your gudiance is so good for me in SPFX